# Redirect www.mysite.com/XYZ_404err_variety to www.mysite.com, how?

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I get 404 errs with tangling urls such as `www.mysite.com/XYZ_404err_variety`, I want to redirect everything like that to `www.mysite.com/`, how? I am using *ix -server on apahce. I tried this one but it messed up my configurations for some reason:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
redirect 404 ^(.*)$ www\.mysite\.com$1 [R]
```

and this one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
redirect 404 ^(www\.mysite\.com*)$ www\.mysite\.com$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status flag on `Redirect` alters the status code returned with the redirect, as opposed to handling the error pages for specific status codes.

It sounds like instead of that, you're looking to send 404-responded requests to your root page:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
```

Comment: Yes that is totally right! It worked. I cannot understand the sentence `"The status flag on Redirect alters the status code returned with the redirect, as opposed to handling the error pages for specific status codes."`, can you clarify? The `"redirect 404 ..."` can change 404 status code to ABC status-code?! The thing `"ErrorDocument 404 ..."` is simple redirection from the status-code to the url?!

Comment: Basically, what that does is allows your redirect action to specify the response code that it uses - so you can pick `301` for permanent, `302` for "found", etc.  It's setting a status code for a response that it's already handling, whereas `ErrorDocument` is being used in *reaction* to a status code being generated elsewhere.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Do you mean: `"ErrorDocument 404 302"` is valid but `"Redirect 404 302"` makes no sense? Sorry I need to make more work to understand your writing, could you offer some good reference material? Some man -page in *ix -machine about this topic?

Comment: Actually neither of those work - `ErrorDocument` must react to an error code with a different document (not a different error code), which `Redirect` must do a valid redirect (but can tack a status code modification in there if desired).